# Way to add same keys to delta table merge

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I have a delta table. Inside this delta table, contains duplicate keys. For example:

```
id  age
1   22
1   23
1   25
2   22
2   11
```

When merging a new table to the delta table that looks like this:

```
id  age
1   23
1   24
1   23
2   21
2   12
```

Using this function:

```
def upsertToDelta(microBatchOutputDF):
    (student_table.alias("t").merge(
        microBatchOutputDF.alias("s"),
       "s.id = t.id")
        .whenMatchedUpdateAll()
        .whenNotMatchedInsertAll()
        .execute())
```

It throws an error:

```
Cannot perform Merge as multiple source rows matched and attempted to modify the same
```

I understand why this is happening, but what I'd like to know is how I can remove the old keys and insert the new keys even though the ids are the same. So the resulting table should look like this:

```
id  age
1   23
1   24
1   23
2   21
2   12
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The keys must be unique for merge to join and the id column isn't, the only way I can see it being possible for your example is if order of the rows within a table is the same in both datasets, but I don't think it can be assured on delta without specific columns to apply row_number() on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like `SCD type 1` change, where we overwrite the old data with the new ones. To handle this, you must have atleast one unique to act as merge key. A simple `row_number` can also be sufficient in your case, like this:

**Before Merge:**

[image]

Add row_number, partitioned by id column, in new data. This is handled in the merge statement below. (Just printing here for understanding)

[image]

**Merge SQL:**

```
MERGE INTO student_table AS target
USING (
  SELECT id AS merge_key, id, age
  FROM microBatchOutputDF
  WHERE id IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT id
      FROM student_table
      )
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT NULL AS merge_key, id, age
  FROM microBatchOutputDF
  WHERE id IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT id
      FROM student_table
      )
  ) AS source
  ON target.id = source.id 
  AND target.id = source.merge_key

WHEN MATCHED
  THEN
    DELETE

WHEN NOT MATCHED AND source.merge_key IS NULL
  THEN
    INSERT (target.id, target.row_num, target.age)
    VALUES (source.id, 1, source.age)
;
```

**The result:**

[image]

Comment: @user2896120 Upvote answer, if it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Will this still work if for example we have 10 rows in the source table with Id of 1 and 3 rows in the new table with id  of 1? The result of this should be all rows of id of 1 in source should be removed, while the 3 rows should be added in

Comment: Yes, it will still work. Its because, there is also a `NOT MATCHED` clause in the MERGE statement. Try out!

Comment: I just tried it out, but it didn't work. So for example the table we have now has three ids of 1 right? The new table that we have has let's say only 1 id of one. The logic should be that all three ids of 1 should be removed and only that one id of 1 should be added in from the new table. But instead the ids of one from before we merge stay and only one gets replaced. What I'd like to happen is something like this: `select * from student_table
where id not in (select id from microBatchOutputDF)
union all
select * from microBatchOutputDF`

Comment: @user2896120 Yes, its still doable with the `MERGE` statement, with a small trick using one more merge_key. Updated answer, and verified it works. (You can ignore the row_number in the SQL and modify it, its not needed anymore). Let me know if it worked. Happy Learning!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This won't work if there are new keys in the new table because it will only match on keys in both tables. I've updated the query by removing the where clause in the second table of the union when creating source. Which makes it more simple! Are there ways to make it even more simple do you think?

Comment: I think you are adding more requirements. You should freeze it in the question if possible :)

Comment: This query is even pretty simple, and if you look into the DAG of the Spark Job, its already performant in my opinion.

Comment: You're great, thank you!